# Extracting values from parsed xml text

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I am using [lxml](https://lxml.de/) to parse the following XML text block:

```
<block>{<block_content><argument_list>(<argument><expr><name><name>String</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>, <argument><expr><name><name>Object</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>)</argument_list></block_content>}</block> 
<block>{<block_content><argument_list>(<argument><expr><literal type="string">"Expected exception to be thrown"</literal></expr></argument>)</argument_list></block_content>}</block> 
<block>{<block_content></block_content>}</block>
```

My requirement is to print the following from the above xml snippet:

> 1. String.class
> 2. Object.class
> 3. "Expected exception to be thrown"

Basically, I need to print the text values contained within the `argument` node of the xml snippet.

Below is the code block that I am using.

```
from lxml import etree

xml_text = '<unit>' \
           '<block>{<block_content><argument_list>(<argument><expr><name><name>String</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>, <argument><expr><name><name>Object</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>)</argument_list></block_content>}</block> ' \
           '<block>{<block_content><argument_list>(<argument><expr><literal type="string">"Expected exception to be thrown"</literal></expr></argument>)</argument_list></block_content>}</block> ' \
           '<block>{<block_content></block_content>}</block>' \
           '</unit>'

tree = etree.fromstring(xml_text)

args = tree.xpath('//argument_list/argument')
for i in range(len(args)):
    print('%s. %s' %(i+1, etree.tostring(args[i]).decode("utf-8")))
```

However, the below output produced by this code does not meet my requirement.

```
1. <argument><expr><name><name>String</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>, 
2. <argument><expr><name><name>Object</name><operator>.</operator><name>class</name></name></expr></argument>)
3. <argument><expr><literal type="string">"Expected exception to be thrown"</literal></expr></argument>)
```

Would appreciate it if someone can point out what modifications I need to make to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the [strip_tags](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree-module.html#strip_tags) function gets the job done. Below is the updated code:

```
for i in range(len(args)):
    etree.strip_tags(args[i], "*")
    print('%s. %s' %(i+1, args[i].text))
```

Output from the update code:

> 1. String.class
> 2. Object.class
> 3. "Expected exception to be thrown"